# Getting Network Init NullReferenceException even though I'm running NetworkTransport.Init()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I've got something wrong here but not sure how it's wrong. I'm getting the error:

> NullReferenceException: Before using the library you should call Init() and do not forget to call Shutdown() afterwards
>
> Server.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Server.cs:69)

... even though i'm calling `NetworkTransport.Init();` on the first line in Start(). What am I missing?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Server : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D textureToSend;
    string messageToSend = "Test Message";

    private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 100;
    private int port = 5701;
    private int hostId;
    private int webHostId;
    private int reliableChannel;
    private int reliableSeqChannel;
    private int reliableFragChannel;
    private int unreliableChannel;
    private int unreliableSeqChannel;

    private bool isStarted = false;
    private byte error;

    private GameObject infoDisplayText;

    private void Start()
    {
        NetworkTransport.Init();
        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        reliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableSequenced);
        reliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableFragmented);
        unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
        unreliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableSequenced);

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

        hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null);

        if (NetworkTransport.IsStarted)
        {
            isStarted = true;
            Debug.Log("NetworkTransport is Started.");
            infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "NetworkTransport is Started.\n";
        }

        Debug.Log("Server Started.");
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Server Started.\n";
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isStarted)
            return;

        int recHostId;
        int connectionId;
        int channelId;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;

        NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive
            (out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);

        switch (recData)
        {
            case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
                Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + " has connected");
                infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Player " + connectionId + " has connected\n";
                break;

            case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:
                break;

            case NetworkEventType.DisconnectEvent:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void SendOnButtonPress()
    {
        SendTexture(textureToSend, messageToSend);
    }

    //Call to send the Texture and a simple string message
    public void SendTexture(Texture2D texture, string message)
    {
        TextureMessage msg = new TextureMessage();

        //Convert Texture2D to byte array

        msg.textureBytes = texture.GetRawTextureData();
        msg.message = message;

        NetworkServer.SendToAll(MyMsgType.texture, msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Init() is not being called on the first line.

Comment: Which line of code are you getting that error on? @RH6 
 `NetworkTransport.Init()` is being called. It doesn't have to be on the first line. Must be called before using the Network API

Comment: @Programmer I'm getting the error at line `NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive (out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);` which is inside my Update function. It's seems strange because update doesn't run until the network is initialized and started. (Update doesn't run until isStarted = true)

Comment: I ran this code on my PC and it worked. No such error

Comment: Is this actually what your code look like or did you change it before posting it?

Comment: it actually looks like this. it's strange. i'm going to go through things again and see where i went wrong

Comment: so i created a new unity project. added this class and now it's working fine!

Comment: i have no idea where the original problem was originating from. if i track it down i'll be sure and post it.

Answer (score 0):

Set `port` before `NetworkTransport.Init()` **like:**

- `NetworkManager.singleton.networkPort = 7777;`
- `NetworkTransport.Init();`

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem happened when I called `Initialize()` or `StartAsClient()` on the `NetworkDiscovery` right at `Start()`. The solution was just to wait a second and then call those methods.